# How to select a specific returned variable from a number of returned variable in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def check(x):
    s = x + 10 
    z = x*10
    y = x - 10
    return s,z,y

print(check(10))
```

In the above piece of code I am returning **three** values s, z and y from the function *check(x)*. Everything else is fine but my concern is that if I wish to select a **specific** variable (for example z) from the function *check(x)*, how can I do that? I don't wish to change the function.

Comment: `print(check(10)[1])` ?

Comment: Your function returns a tuple, and items can be selected from a tuple by index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use tuple unpacking:

```py
a, b, c = check(10)
```

where `b` will be the element `z` from your function.  Or you can select just the 1-indexed element from the returned tuple.

```
d = check(10)[1]
```

Comment: Using the second method it says "Attempt to index a number value"

Answer (score 1):

You could choose a specific return value by using an index. For example, `print(check(10)[1])` would print out the value with the index of 1, which in this case would be 100. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this way:

```
_, x,_  = check(10)
```